# List with inner List to Map Java Stream Api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of elements:

```
List<OuterElement> outerElements;
```

OuterElement object has 2 property:

```
String key;

List<InnerElement> innerElements;
```

InnerElement object has 1 property:

```
String value;
```

I need to create a map where for each innerElement will be created an Entry, where key will be outerElement key, and value will be innerElement value;

```
Map<String, String> // actually Map<OuterElement.key, InnerElement.value>
```

How to do it using Stream API?

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
       Map<String, String> result = outerElements.stream()
        .forEach(outerElement -> outerElement.getInnerElements().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(OuterElement::getKey, InnerElement::getValue));
```

Comment: Keys in map must be unique, so if you have `outer:key, inner[val1,val2]` then your map can't be `key:val1, key:val2`. It could be `key:[val1,val2]` but this would require changing it from `Map<String,String>` to `Map<String,List<String>>`.

Comment: What should happen if two of the outer elements in the list happen to have the same key?  And since each outer element has a list of inner elements, each of which has a value, it's not really clear what you're looking for.  E.g., imagine you have `[OuterElement(key=x, innerElements=[InnerElement(value=y), InnerElement(value=z)]), OuterElement(key=a, innerElements=[InnerElement(value=b), InnerElement(value=c)])]`.  What should the result be?

Comment: `Map<OuterElement.key, InnerElement.value> ` is a one-to-one relationship, while you've got a one-to-many connection (which is either `Map<OuterElement.key, Set<InnerElement.value>>` or `Map<OuterElement.key, List<InnerElement.value>>`)

Comment: Give us example of possible input and expected output (this will probably let *you* realize why your attempt "doesn't work" and let you make decision what do do instead).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023961/5350482) answer for java 8 you could use this one:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> collect = elements.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OuterElement::getKey,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), outers -> outers.stream()
                .flatMap(o -> o.getInnerElements().stream())
                .map(InnerElement::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

if you could use something like [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html):

```
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = elements.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OuterElement::getKey,
            LinkedMultiValueMap::new,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), outers -> outers.stream()
                .flatMap(o -> o.getInnerElements().stream())
                .map(InnerElement::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Comment: Should say that `MultiValueMap` is taken from spring framework, but anyway +1 for solution